# Word for the original enamor with an idea or concept

Tags: single-word-requests

Like, for example, a child wanting to go to space when he gets older. He is fascinated by this concept, even though not having experienced it. It's based on amped up perceptions.

Comment: a child's fantasy...

Comment: "romanticizing" is a good fit, but it has too much negative context, it need not be bad

Comment: simply holding something in high regard

Comment: "childhood dream"?

Comment: Hi Harsh, welcome to English Language & Usage. You might not be aware that there are strict rules for [tag:single-word-requests]: "To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. You must include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used."  You can add these details by clicking on the [edit] link. :-)